# How do I run an autocomplete $search on multiple fields?

Tags: mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

The [documentation](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/autocomplete/#autocomplete-ref) states that the `path` needs to be a `string` and not an array of strings. I just want to confirm that that is in fact the only possibility, and if, in either case, there is a recommended way to do this.

*e.g.* I want to search (with autocompletion) my movies for the text `"hammer"` on both the `title` and the `plot`

In the current scenario I can implement a search by either `title` or `plot` with ease. But If I try to do it for both, making `path` an array of strings, which is acceptable on other operators, I get an error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63186815/create-querystring-search-pipeline-that-returns-result-not-only-by-word-bounda <-- check out that answer. It's the same problem in solution with more data. It should solve your problem..

Answer (score 15):

If you are trying to match on title and plot, use **should:** in **compound** operator

create autocomplete search index on both fields : **title** and **plot**

```
$search: {
    compound: {
        should: [
            {
                autocomplete: {
                    query:'hammer',
                    path: 'title',
                },
            },
            {
                autocomplete: {
                    query:'hammer',
                    path: 'plot',
                },
            },
        ],
    },
},
```