# Create queryString $search pipeline, that returns result not only by word boundaries in MongoDB atlass search

Tags: mongodb-atlas-search

My objective is to create a search pipeline in MongoDB, that returns result for multiple fields.

My index:

```
{
  "analyzer": "lucene.standard",
  "searchAnalyzer": "lucene.standard",
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "fields": {
      "description": {
        "analyzer": "lucene.standard",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My `$search` pipeline stage:

```js
{
    $search: {
        index: 'lucene.standard',
        queryString: {
            defaultPath: 'name',
            query: `name:"${query}" OR description:"${query}"`,

        },
    }
}
```

This works, but *only* when I search for a full word.
For example, if a have a document with description `fooBar`.
My problem is that if I query for `foo` - I get **no** results.
Only works when I query for the full word `fooBar`.

How can I fix this - maybe be using another index definition?

Answer (score 4):

Did the previous solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62823054/query-for-sub-set-of-word-in-mongodb-atlas-full-text-search?rq=1) work for you? As defined in the [documentation](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/autocomplete/):

> The **autocomplete** operator performs a search for a word or phrase that
> contains a sequence of characters from an incomplete input string.

```
{
  "analyzer": "lucene.standard",
  "searchAnalyzer": "lucene.standard",
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "fields": {
        "description": {
            "type": "autocomplete"
          },        
        "name": {
          "type": "autocomplete"
        }        
    }
  }
}
```

Your search stage is also a bit off. Maybe try a [compound](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/compound/) operator:

```
{
  $search: {
    "compound": {
      "should": [{
          "autocomplete": {
            "query": "foo",
            "path": "name"
          },
          "autocomplete": {
            "query": "foo",
            "path": "description"
          }
        }]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How to specify the two indexes for name and description?